# Multi-modal public transport Routing using pgrouting or opentripplanner

Tags: pgrouting

I need multi-modal public transport routing for my iPhone app and also to solve a TSP problem.

I have been researching and I am unable to make a decision whether I should go with pgrouting or install Open Trip Planner.. Is there a chart comparison, what each of them offers and what is different about these softwares?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pgRouting does not support multi-modal routing.

There has been a Google Summer of Code project and its source code can be found in a branch of the project repository, but it has not been integrated into pgRouting 2.x (yet).